# jQuery.post doesn't return data if it gets Codeigniter php error

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to post this to the update_offer controller.

```
$.post(site_url+"/offer/update_offer", { variable: 'asdf' },
function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

This will will normally return everything perfectly and alert the data. No problems.

The problem occur when I use:

```
$this->db->where('oID = '.$offer['oID'].' AND oCompanyid = '.$this->session->userdata('company'));
$this->db->update('offers',$offer);
```

... and it fails. Then it will not return or alert anything.
If I go to the same page with my browser I get "A Database Error Occurred... ", which is just a html page.

Why doesn't that get returned in the $.post script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy you shoude use $.ajax to handle request. You woulde be able to make more configuration tought.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Bla.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```